# Checking if items in one list start or end with any one of many items of a second list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In excel, what's the best way to check if a list of strings in a column start or end with another list of strings?

Example:

**INPUT**

List 1:
Reddy
CodeRed
Zabby
KaBlueY

List 2:
 
Red
Blue
Blop
Blurp

**OUTPUT**

Column START should return:
Reddy - TRUE (because it contains 'red' from the second list in the start position)
CodeRed - FALSE (because it does not contain any strings from the second list in the start position.
Zabby - FALSE (because it does not contain any strings from the second list in the start position.
KaBlueY - FALSE (because it does not contain any strings from the second list in the start position.

Column END should return:
Reddy - FALSE (because it does not contain any strings from the second list in the end position.)
CodeRed - TRUE (because it contains 'red' from the second list in the end position)
Zabby - FALSE (because it does not contain any strings from the second list in the end position)
KaBlueY - FALSE (because it does not contain any strings from the second list in the end position)

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB61G.png)

Answer (score 0):

**This issue can be solved using one `Helper Column` and `LEFT`, `RIGHT` function:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Above shown sample data has **List 1** in 
  `A2:A7` and **List 2** in `D2:D6`.
- To get helper values enter this Array 
  (CSE) formula in Cell `E2`, finish with 
  **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and fill down.

**`{=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$6,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$2:$D$6,A2)),)),"")}`**

- To get **Column START**, enter this 
  Formula in Cell `B2` & fill down.

  ```
  =IF(E2="","     FALSE",LEFT(A2,LEN(E2))=E2)
  ```
- For **Column End**, enter this Formula in 
  Cell `C2` and fill down.

  ```
  =IF(E2="","     FALSE",RIGHT(A2,LEN(E2))=E2)
  ```

**N.B.**

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. The input lists (List 1 & List 2) are separate from the output columns. The output columns (Start, End) need to be based on List 1, checked against strings in list 2. For example, Reddy - Does Reddy have any strings from list 2 in the start? Separately, does it contain any strings from list 2 in the end position? See revisions above. Thank you

Comment: @Zauberflöte, my answer is based on your first post ,, which has been edited after wards,, be careful while post the question since any change after the answer is not good practice!! Better upload the expected Output .

Comment: Rajesh, I edited the question only to clarify what I was looking for. Thanks for your patience on this. Please help!

Comment: @Zauberflöte,, better post Screen Shot for the expected output, will help me to compare with mine post to fix the issue!!

Comment: I added a screenshot at the bottom. Please have a look

Comment: @Zauberflöte,, now check the revised answer !!

Comment: Rajesh, thank you, this almost works. Suppose list one contains the term "RedBlue." Currently, the helper column identifies only one match and so the output would return ("True") for start and "False" for end instead of "True", "True".  Any ideas on this?

Comment: @Zauberflöte, since for `RedBlue` the `Helper Col` returns `Red` so that `Start Col` finds it `True` and `False` for `End Col`. If you also feel that your basis issue has been solved then you may accept my post as Answer ,, up vote also ☺

Comment: I upvoted the answer but my issue still exists. I need to determine if there is a match in start or finish or both start and finish such as in with "RedBlue" described above.